# fwknop & lots of logins

Tags: ssh, firewall

I set up fwknop to a server (managed by ansible).
I have set up `.ssh/config` to automate port knocking.
When I run (ansible) scripts, they will connect to the server multiple times, increasing execute speed significantly.

How can I achive that fwknop is not invoked just when it is needed?

I can automate it with a small wrapper script which checks the availability of the host and knoks when necessary but I cannot believe there is no standard switch somewhere for this scenario.

`.ssh/config` excerpt:

```
Match host my.remote.host exec "fwknop -v -n %h"
```

Comment: Port knocking is extremely rare. Most of us just secure our systems instead. Anyway you'll probably need to share the specifics of how you configured ssh and how you configured ansible to use ssh.

Comment: The ansible part is irrelevant. The point is that the script makes ssh connections multiple times. And knocking is time consuming.

Comment: It sounds that you have a definite list, which needs to be done before fwknop. Could you give me a list of those taks?